# Load Xml file with checkbox value

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Im working on some small WPF project, with user inputs, three for strings and one for checkbox.
When the user has filled every input the information will save as an xml file.
When i try to load the informations back into the input fields, it works with the strings but not the checkbox. Every file i load, the checkbox is always unchecked.

What am i missing ?

This is how i save the information.

```
  private void savebtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "CompressorTypeList"; 
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml"; 
            dlg.Filter = "XML documents (.xml)|*.xml"; 

            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            Information info = new Information();
                info.StudentName = txtbox1.Text;
                info.StudentID = txtbox2.Text;
                info.StudentPassword = txtbox3.Password;
                info.BoolDataValue = (bool)ckbox.IsChecked;
            SaveXml.savedata(info, filename);
            txtbox1.Text = null;
            txtbox2.Text = null;
            txtbox3.Password = null;
            ckbox.IsChecked = false;
        }
```

And this is how i load the informations back.

```
 private void PopulateXMLData()
        {

            try
            {

                var openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
                openFile.Filter = "XML documents (.xml)|*.xml";
                Nullable<bool> result = openFile.ShowDialog();

                string XMLFilePath = openFile.FileName;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(XMLFilePath);

                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                   
                        txtbox1.Text = dr["StudentName"].ToString().Trim();
                        txtbox2.Text = dr["StudentID"].ToString().Trim();
                        txtbox3.Password = dr["StudentPassword"].ToString().Trim();
                        ckbox.IsChecked = (bool)dr["BoolDataValue"];
                    

                }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Load error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to look at the method SaveXml.savedata(info, filename); which saves rows to xml file.  The issue is with this method being compatible with the reading of the XML.

Comment: @jdweng this is my savedata method.   `  public static void savedata(object obj, string filename)
            {
                XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
                sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
                writer.Close();
            }`

Comment: You have open the xml file with notepad and see what is inside.  You are creating the xml file using serialize and then reading the xml using the DataSet method ReadXml().  I think the issue is with the element "BoolDataValue".  The name of the tag when you write is not the same as the name when you read.